# QML: Cannot open: file:///images/1.png

Tags: qml

I have simple ListModel which should contain png images.
I have listed png files in resource file.
I get "Cannot open: file:///images/1.png" when trying
to run in simulator. I am using QT Creator.

dir:

```
main.cpp
test.qrc
qml/test/main.qml
images/1.png
images/2.png
images/3.png
```

test.qrc:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>images/0.png</file>
        <file>images/1.png</file>
        <file>images/2.png</file>
        <file>images/3.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

main.qml:

```
ListModel {
    ListElement { icon: ":/images/1.png"}
    ListElement { icon: ":/images/2.png"}
    ListElement { icon: ":/images/3.png"}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution. The following statements are both working in simulator (GNU/Linux) and target system (Nokia N9):

```
   ListElement { icon: "qrc:images/1.png"}
   ListElement { icon: "qrc:/images/1.png"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try without the "/"

```
ListModel {
    ListElement { icon: ":images/1.png"}
    ListElement { icon: ":images/2.png"}
    ListElement { icon: ":images/3.png"}
}
```

Comment: Already tried and not working. I get `Cannot open: file:///home/meolic/QtProjects/Test-build-simulator-Simulator_Qt_for_GCC__Qt_SDK___izdaja_/qml/Test/images/1.png`

Comment: The system is Nokia N9 (MeeGo Harmattan). Images do not exist in the target directory, they are stated as resources and therefore compiled into binary executable. Executable is 432 kB and if I remove images from resource file the executable becames only 26 kB (I have more than 3 images).